# Firebase ML Kit class not found when used in Unity3D Android Plugin

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

Firebase MLKit, specifically the vision component for face detection doesn't currently have an official unity3D plugin. I'm trying to create an android module then import into Unity3D as a plugin via the use of Unity's AndroidJavaClass interface. (build module -> copy classes.jar to unity's Plugin/Android folder). My issue is the plugin works correctly but whenever it tries to call any line associated with Firebase I'm getting the errors below. Does anybody know what's the issue? I assume it's just a simple dependency issue but I'm having trouble fixing it.

The line that's being called. It's copied straight from the official docs and works if I keep the module as a native android app within android studio.

```
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions;

FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions options =
        new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE)
                .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .build();
```

The error that's producing (only as a unity3d plugin)

```
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   : AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions$Builder;
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions$Builder;
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   :      at com.danq.faceplugin.FaceD.Init(FaceD.java:14)
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:0)
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:95)
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   :      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   :      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
12-14 16:15:17.934 29990 30008 E Unity   : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Danq.FaceBeatsUnityGame-4MLAWSIBswXt4mPwAhlr_Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Danq.FaceBeatsUnityGame-4MLAWSIBswXt4mPwAhlr_Q
```

The module's gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android
        {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"


    defaultConfig
            {
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()

            }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that your library has some dependencies that would be captured in a pure Android Studio application. Unfortunately, these dependencies are not captured or communicated via your `aar` archive, and need to be replicated in Unity's build system.

I think that the best way to work around this issue is to have Unity [generate a mainTemplate.gradle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html) file for you. If you let the Play Services Resolver patch your mainTemplate.gradle ([I cover this step by step here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef) with images), all of your dependencies will be in one place.

Then you should be able to go down to the `dependencies` section of your `mainTemplate.gradle` file and add

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
```

just as you did in your library. Be sure to *NOT* place your dependency between `// Android Resolver Dependencies Start` and `// Android Resolver Dependencies End`, and do not delete `**DEPS**`.

Now, there are a couple other options as well. You could build your library into a local maven repository and include the dependencies this way. Since I have not done this myself, I can't provide detailed instructions. But then, you could include your library and its transitive dependencies [just like the Firebase plugin itself](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef) (apologies for using the same link twice).

You can also try changing `implementation` to `api` for your library, but I do not believe that this *actually* embeds the dependencies into your generated `aar` archive. If you do this and it fixes the issue without the above gradle file changes, certainly let me know! You can find more information on `api` vs. `implementation` [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa).

I hope this helps!

--Patrick